# SQLite Net DateTimeKind is Unspecified when reading a date back from the database

Tags: c#, datetime, sqlite-net

storeDateTimeAsTicks is the default behaviour in recent SQLite Net implementations and it also has a performance advantage compared to storing as string.

Unfortunately, when saving the DateTime ticks to the database it ignores the timezone and when reading the DateTime back from the database it initialises the DateTime object with the ticks leaving the DateTimeKind of the object to unspecified.

Given the way DateTime works, it means that to get a DateTime with DateTimeKind.Local back from the database, you need to convert to UTC before saving to the database, and convert to local time after reading from the database.

Is there a way to have SQLite Net deal with the roundtrip on its own?
I would like to avoid having pre-processing and post-processing of objects during serialisation and deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime.
With DateTimeOffset the time and the time zone are stored and you can use the LocalDateTime and UtcDateTime properties as needed.

Comment: Sqlite.Net by default stores Datetimeoffset.Utcticks and looses the timezone info so it won't solve the issue.